# How to extract the t-value as a bare number in R?

Tags: r, function, vector, statistics, t-test

I've tried to `unname()` and use `[[1]]` to *only* extract the numeric value of `t` reported after a `t.test()` with no success.

I was wondering how I could extract the numeric value of `t` in a `t.test` command in R?

**Here is an example:**

```
t.value = unname(t.test(extra ~ group, var.equal = T, data = sleep))[[1]]

(gt = t.value / .2)  ## When you run this

#>         t   ## You see this extra `t` here, how to avoid getting this `t`?
#  -9.304067
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unname` should be after the extraction

```
t.value <- unname(t.test(extra ~ group, var.equal = T, data = sleep)[[1]])
t.value
#[1] -1.860813
```

Or other option is

```
t.test(extra ~ group, var.equal = T, data = sleep)$statistic[["t"]]
#[1] -1.860813
```

Or we can use `as.numeric`

---

In the OP's code, it is `unname`ing the `list` elements

```
t.valueO <- t.test(extra ~ group, var.equal = T, data = sleep)
names(t.valueO)
#[1] "statistic"   "parameter"   "p.value"     "conf.int"    "estimate"    "null.value"  "alternative" "method"     
#[9] "data.name"  

names(unname(t.valueO))
#NULL
```